# Optimize Expected value of noisy data (stochastic aproximation)

Tags: probability, optimization, stochastic-processes, stochastic-approximation

I have a simulation that gives me noisy/stochastic data for every vector of parameters I put into it. So for the simulation data we can consider a function: 
$$
F(\theta ,\xi )
$$

where $\theta$ is our parameter vector and $\xi$ is a random variable.
Now I want to optimize the parameters $\theta$ for the expected value: 
$$
f(\theta) = \mathbf{E}\left [ F(\theta ,\xi ) \right ]
$$
$$\theta_{min} = argmin(f(\theta))
$$

I thought about using a simplex algorithm and for each data point I could run a monte carlo simulation which gives me the expected value of any point in the parameter space. But since each simulation run can take more than 10 sec this isn't a feasible method.

**Please** tell my if this is acceptable from a mathematical point of view at least!

In a paper I read a method used for this type of problems is "stochastic aproximation" AMONG OTHERS.

So my question is what are these other methods to solve such a optimization problem and what method/algorithm is actually used in practice for my example and perhaps even available in software like matlab or python?

Answer (score 1):

One general approach is to run simulations for a variety of values of $\theta$ and treat the resulting observed outputs $\hat{F}(\theta_1;\epsilon_1),\dots, \hat{F}(\theta_N; \epsilon_N)$ as a random sample. Fit a regression function (typically not linear, but preferably smooth and ideally convex), then find the optimal value $\theta^*$ of the fitted function. Some people will then design a new experiment, with $\theta$ values clustered around $\theta^*$ and less disperse than the orginal $theta$ sample, and repeat *ad nauseum*.

Techniques like this are frequently treated in text books on simulation. A good search phrase to use is "response surface methodology". Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology.

Comment: Yes I thought about that too. Thanks for your answer. Have you heard about the stochastic approximation approach I mentioned? An if so can you name any disadvantages of stochastic approximation over your "fit and optimize" technique, because at the first look the approach of optimizing over the noisy data directly seems more elegant... 
Also please consider upvoting my question so I have a high enough score to upvote your answer.

Comment: "Simplex algorithm" usually refers to a linear programming algorithm, but I'm guessing you mean a "hill climbing" algorithm that I think goes by the same name. That would work, and might take less effort, with the caveat that you could easily be trapped at a local optimum if the true response function $f(\theta)$ is not convex in $\theta$. You would need to run multiple replications at each sample value of $\theta$, of course.

Comment: Algorithmically, I might prefer your approach to get $\theta_opt$. It would not provide any insight into the nature (shape) of the response function (disadvantage), and if you are planning to publish some referee might gag on it as too ad hoc (disadvantage), but if you just need $\theta_opt$ it would be faster, easier and (assuming convexity and equal sample sizes for both methods) likely no less accurate (advantages).